# How to remove a bullet when it reaches a certain amount of distance? JAVA Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I want my program to remove the object that is no longer visible in the window of the player to save memory. I try something like this:

In the game class  (render method):

```
if(fireDelay >= 0.4f){
           Laser laser = new Laser();
           laser.shoot(nave.getRotation(), nave.getX(), nave.getY());
           escenario.addActor(laser);
           if(laser.getLimit()){
             escenario.addAction(Actions.removeActor(laser));
             fireDelay = 0;       
           }
       }
```

In the laser class

```
public boolean getLimit(){
    return limit;
}

@Override
public void act(float dt){
    super.act(dt);
    elapsedTime += dt;
    distancia += dt;
     setRotation(rotacion);      
    if(distancia == 0.4f)
        limit = true;
}
```

But obviously... is not working... I also saw that you can handle bullets with arraylist, but I try to do it and I could not get it ... ¿How could we accomplish this?

Comment: You are saying 3 things here. You want to remove the bullet when: 1: The bullet is not visible to the player. 2: When the bullet has traveled a set distance. 3: When bullet has been alive for 4 seconds.    Which one is it?

Comment: @IronMonkey the last thing you mentioned (as seen in the code) is how I'm doing (taking time with dt) .... either distance or time, no matter as the way you do, I just want to remove the bullet of the game...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I just have to add this line of code:

```
laser.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(2), Actions.fadeOut(0.5f), Actions.visible(false)) );
```

before the shooting, store the object in a arrayList then iterate and delete them.

```
 removeList = new ArrayList<Laser>();

 for ( Laser laser : laserList )
 {
 wraparound( laser );
 if ( !laser.isVisible() )
 removeList.add( laser );
 }
 for (Laser ba : removeList)
 {
 ba.destroy();
 }
```

I have found that it works because I started to shoot randomly throughout the game screen and the game never got slow or freeze!